# How to replace the text between two characters in c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace

I am bit confused writing the regex for finding the Text between the two delimiters **{ }** and replace the text with another text in c#,how to replace?

I tried this.

```
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:abc.txt");
        string line;
        line = sr.ReadLine();

        while (line != null)
        {

            if (line.StartsWith("<"))
            {
                if (line.IndexOf('{') == 29)
                {
                    string s = line;
                    int start = s.IndexOf("{");
                    int end = s.IndexOf("}");
                    string result = s.Substring(start+1, end - start - 1);

                }
            }
            //write the lie to console window
            Console.Write Line(line);
            //Read the next line
            line = sr.ReadLine();
        }
        //close the file
        sr.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I want replace the found text(result) with another text.

Answer (score 13):

Use Regex with pattern: `\{([^\}]+)\}`

```
Regex yourRegex = new Regex(@"\{([^\}]+)\}");
string result = yourRegex.Replace(yourString, "anyReplacement");
```

Comment: +1, although I think you can get away without escaping the `}` inside the character class.

Answer (score 13):

```
string s = "data{value here} data";
int start = s.IndexOf("{");
int end = s.IndexOf("}", start);
string result = s.Substring(start+1, end - start - 1);
s = s.Replace(result, "your replacement value");
```

Comment: Thanks for giving reply.

Comment: I think this is the most simplest answer. I don't think you need start in your second parameter of result though. you just need (end - 1)

Comment: Code below was in my case more suitable as it takes into consideration not only 1 character. When we use the type of quotation marks as above we suggest that we can use longer text - string instead of a character. 
`int start = text.IndexOf("Text between this...") + start.Length;

int end = text.IndexOf("...and this");

string oldValueToBeReplaced = text.Substring(start, end - start);

s = s.Replace(oldValueToBeReplaced , "your replacement value");`

Answer (score 8):

To get the string between the parentheses to be replaced, use the Regex pattern

```
    string errString = "This {match here} uses 3 other {match here} to {match here} the {match here}ation";
    string toReplace =  Regex.Match(errString, @"\{([^\}]+)\}").Groups[1].Value;    
    Console.WriteLine(toReplace); // prints 'match here'
```

To then replace the text found you can simply use the Replace method as follows:

```
string correctString = errString.Replace(toReplace, "document");
```

Explanation of the Regex pattern:

```
\{                 # Escaped curly parentheses, means "starts with a '{' character"
        (          # Parentheses in a regex mean "put (capture) the stuff 
                   #     in between into the Groups array" 
           [^}]    # Any character that is not a '}' character
           *       # Zero or more occurrences of the aforementioned "non '}' char"
        )          # Close the capturing group
\}                 # "Ends with a '}' character"
```

Comment: adding in the explanation of the regex pattern used greatly adds to the answer since people looking at questions like this in general won't have much knowledge of using regex +1

Answer (score 2):

The following regular expression will match the criteria you specified:

```
string pattern = @"^(\<.{27})(\{[^}]*\})(.*)";
```

The following would perform a replace:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$1 REPLACE $3");
```

For the input: `"<012345678901234567890123456{sdfsdfsdf}sadfsdf"` this gives the output `"<012345678901234567890123456 REPLACE sadfsdf"`

Answer (score 1):

You need two calls to `Substring()`, rather than one: One to get `textBefore`, the other to get `textAfter`, and then you concatenate those with your replacement.

```
int start = s.IndexOf("{");
int end = s.IndexOf("}");
//I skip the check that end is valid too avoid clutter
string textBefore = s.Substring(0, start);
string textAfter = s.Substring(end+1);
string replacedText = textBefore + newText + textAfter;
```

If you want to keep the braces, you need a small adjustment:

```
int start = s.IndexOf("{");
int end = s.IndexOf("}");
string textBefore = s.Substring(0, start-1);
string textAfter = s.Substring(end);
string replacedText = textBefore + newText + textAfter;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Regex expression that some others have already posted, or you can use a more advanced Regex that uses balancing groups to make sure the opening { is balanced by a closing }.

That expression is then `(?<BRACE>\{)([^\}]*)(?<-BRACE>\})`

You can test this expression online at [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/).

You simply match your input string with this Regex pattern, then use the replace methods of Regex, for instance:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<BRACE>\{)([^\}]*)(?<-BRACE>\})", textToReplaceWith);
```

For more C# Regex Replace examples, see http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace.

Comment: Much as I love balancing groups, are they really needed here? If either brace is missing, a standard match will fail anyway.

Comment: Good information to add to the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to use split method if you want to avoid any regex .. this is an aproach :

```
string s = "sometext {getthis}";
string result= s.Split(new char[] { '{', '}' })[1];
```

Comment: That would only work when you know which position will the text between `{}` fall into.