# Remove character between space and a symbol

Tags: c#

I have one string like:

Sonographie Schilddrüse:1
 Sonographie Gynäkologie:1
 Fragestellung: Zust. nach TEP
 evt- Infotyp: FRAGE
 Kennzeichen OBX-Segment
 HL7: FRAGE
 Mobilität: **FG;** Pat. Fußgänger
 Transportart: **GEH;** gehfähig
 Schwangerschaft: 0 
 Patient nüchtern: 0

and would like to remove FG; and GEH;

Is it possible to remove the characters between the symbols : and ; in a string? Can anyone tell me how in C#?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check [String.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [String.Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: `string result = Regex.Repace(myString, @":\s*[A-Z]+;", " ");`

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701818/how-to-replace-the-text-between-two-characters-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Would go for regex replace:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inputString = "Mobilität: FG; Pat. Fußgänger";
        var outputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, ":.+;", ":");
        Console.WriteLine(outputString); 
    }
```