# How to replace string between two characters in whole text?

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I have the following string:

```
{Name}({Age})
```

I want to get the following:

```
()
```

I have tried this code:

```
@"\{([^\}]+)\}" Only return {Name}

"({)(.*)(})" Return {Name}({Age}
```

But none of them worked as I wanted.

How to do this?

Comment: Can you share the code which you have written to solve this problem? And also explain how that is not working for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace the text between two characters in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701818/how-to-replace-the-text-between-two-characters-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = @"{Name}({Age})";

        string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\{.*?\}", "");

        Console.WriteLine(output); // "()"
    }
}
```